Why do we need L2 testnet chains
Theoretically , if the contracts can be tested in l1 testnets like Ethereum sepolia , why do l2 testnet chains exist ?

L2 chains (e.g., Arbitrum, Base, Optimism, zkSync, etc.) implement unique scaling mechanisms like Optimistic Rollups or zk-Rollups.
So, the features like Fraud proving (for Optimistic Rollups) and Validity proofs (for zk-Rollups) cannot be tested on L1 because they rely on specialized architecture and execution models.
Also, L2s significantly reduce transaction costs compared to L1. Testing on an L1 testnet (like Ethereum Sepolia) still mimics L1’s higher costs and slower confirmation times, making it less efficient for iterating on DApp development. So, L2 testnets enable faster, cheaper testing environments.

Thank you Syed , i was very confused

You’re welcome. Keep building!

Suppose if i am developing a swapping application which is supposed to support l1 and many l2s and it is working perfectly fine on sepolia , can you please also explain me the scope of testing the app in l2 testnet chains , because i find it hard to find liquity in the uniswap contracts deployed in the l2 chains

For the liquidity problem, you can manually deposit tokens into Uniswap pools on L2 testnets to create liquidity for your testing. Or, you could also perform forked testing on L2 mainnets instead of using L2 testnets.

Thank you Syed , i will try one of these ways :) .

Layer 2 (L2) testnets exist because they replicate the unique features and environments of L2 solutions, like faster transactions, lower fees, rollup-specific mechanisms (e.g., fraud proofs, ZK-proofs), and bridging to Layer 1. While L1 testnets like Sepolia can test basic contract functionality, they can't simulate the scalability, cost-efficiency, and ecosystem interactions of L2 networks, which are crucial for building and optimizing dApps designed for L2.
